# Integrating ckeditor standard package with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, ckeditor

I downloaded the Standard package from http://ckeditor.com/download and followed everything in this guide https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/CKEditor.

ckeditor is working, however the features that are being displayed is only from the Basic package.
What can possibly cause this?

Comment: This is a tutorial from 2012, and it says: "Please note that the wiki tutorial is outdated, please visit the CKEditor helper homepage to read the up-to-date tutorial." right at the top of this page. Have you tried the instructions from http://nukium.com/developpement/php-frameworks/codeigniter/ckeditor-helper-for-codeigniter/ ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AnnaTomanek! Yes, I have seen this tutorial already. Sadly, still the same results..

Comment: This is a third-party integration effort, so unfortunately I cannot help more. Do note that CKEditor 4 was published in November, 2012, so it's quite possible that this may only work for CKEditor 3.